# How to test a helper within a gem with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I already published my first rails gem but not yet with any tests included. This gem is just a simple helper which I want to test with rspec. But I have no idea how I can test a helper within a gem with rspec.

I tried to create a file spec/helper/development_ribbon_helper_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe DevelopmentRibbonHelper do
end
```

But when I execute rspec I get this error:

```
development_ribbon_helper_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant DevelopmentRibbonHelper (NameError)
```

You can find the whole source code on [github](https://github.com/ding280/development_ribbon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be trying to write a rails engine gem, correct? Since your helper file is located outside of lib/, your spec_helper will need to know how to load your rails engine.

One way to do this is to create a dummy rails app in your spec/ directory. This setup is well-described in this post: http://reinteractive.net/posts/2-start-your-engines.

Alternatively, you can move the helper file into lib/development_ribbon and require it in your development_ribbon.rb file:

```
require "development_ribbon/development_ribbon_helper"
```

Then, in your rails apps that use the gem, you could include the helper in application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include DevelopmentRibbon::DevelopmentRibbonHelper
end
```